# Jax- rs REST Consuming Javascript object

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, jax-rs

I am having problem with consuming javascript object on my webservice. When I consume just a String it works fine but when ever I am trying to send as object it fails

WebService

```
  @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public void POSTTest(Users u)
        {
            System.out.println("Here"+u);

        }
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/test/api/test",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: {

                        firstName: "T"

                },
                success: function (response) {

                    console.log("Hello");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
```

POJO

```
public class Users {

    String firstName;



    public Users() {}

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }
}
```

Mapper

```
 <init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
```

Anyone has any ideas what Iam doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: No error on the server

Comment: From the response header I get 415 error Unsoported Media Type

Comment: try to add a dataType: "json" , Accept: "application/json" in your ajax request

Comment: Tried and same result

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, was missing dependancies for mapping JSON to POJO